# Роман "Обломов" Гончарова

Tags: литература

Подскажите пожалуйста почему в "Обомове" Штольц назначил встречу именно в сиреневом саду.Спасибо

Comment: Вы ничего не путаете?
Сада там как такового не было, были многочисленные ветки и кусты, особенно на даче. 
И кто кому встречу назначал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то не могу вспомнить сцену, где Штольц назначает встречу.

А вообще мотив сирени связан с  переживаниями Обломова. 
  Образ живой благоухающей сирени в пору её полного расцвета-символ расцвета внутреннего мира Обломова, его влюблённости.  Это был «момент символических намёков, знаменательных улыбок, сиреневых веток». О самом главном Ольга и Илья Ильич высказались друг перед другом при помощи «языка» цветущей сирени: ветка сирени, выроненная Ольгой и выдавшая её чувство; сорванная мимоходом ветка и брошенная Ильинской с досадой на землю; та же ветка, подобранная Обломовым как шифр к отгадке поведения Ольги; наконец, новая ветка в руке Ольги как «лучшая половина» жизни, отворяемая Обломову.

В письме Обломова к Ольге её троекратное «люблю» перечёркивается троекратным «нет» автора письма. С этого момента начинает снижаться пафос сиреневого мотива. Не замечая смены времени года, Обломов просит у Ольги ветку как знак.
«- Сирени... отошли, пропали!.. Вон, видите, какие остались: поблеклые!
- Отошли, поблекли! - повторил он, глядя на сирени...».
Увядание метафорически переносится писателем на жертвенное письмо Обломова. «Оно поблекло!» - говорит он, не подозревая в тот миг, что его письмо «расцветёт» в руках Штольца, доказывая невиновность Ольги и дальнозоркую мудрость Ильи Ильича.

Режет слух словосочетание «букет сирени», в которое Штольц вложил холодновато-ироническую интонацию. Но когда Ольга спрашивает, как же ей быть с прошлым, он, не колеблясь, отвечает: «Поблекнет, как ваша сирень!».

Сирень появляется в конце романа как крайнее спасительное средство для Обломова, которому Штольц воодушевлённо рассказывает об Ольге, ставшей его женой, о прелестях деревенской жизни, о сирени: «...Опять забродит у тебя в душе прошлое. Вспомнишь парк, сирень!..». Для Обломова предлагаемое Штольцем «лечение» - невыносимая пытка. «Нет, Андрей, нет, не поминай, не шевели, ради Бога!.. Мне больно от этого, а не отрадно. Воспоминания - или величайшая поэзия, когда они - воспоминания о живом счастье, или жгучая боль, когда они касаются засохших ран...»